# Radio reset will not work

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Im trying to uncheck previously selected radio button of a group of radio buttons that i must give different names to. I am trying to avoid jquery and this is the closest attempt ive gotten so far.

```
function radioUncheck(){
    if (document.forms.form.radioa[1].checked= true){
        document.forms.form.radiob[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioc[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiod[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioe[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiof[1].checked= false;
    }
    else if(document.forms.form.radiob[1].checked= true){
        document.forms.form.radioa[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioc[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiod[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioe[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiof[1].checked= false;
    }
    else if(document.forms.form.radioc[1].checked= true){
        document.forms.form.radioa[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiob[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiod[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioe[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiof[1].checked= false;
    }
    else if(document.forms.form.radiod[1].checked= true){
        document.forms.form.radioa[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiob[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioc[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioe[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiof[1].checked= false;
    }
    else if(document.forms.form.radioe[1].checked= true){
        document.forms.form.radioa[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiob[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioc[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiod[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiof[1].checked= false;
    }
    else if(document.forms.form.radiof[1].checked= true){
        document.forms.form.radioa[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiob[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioc[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radiod[1].checked= false;
        document.forms.form.radioe[1].checked= false;
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

ive also tried replacing `=` with `==` as well as tried to just put .reset for each instead of equals to false... please help!! thank you for your time

HTML Example as follows:

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="radioUncheck()">
    <input type="radio" name="radiob" onclick="radioUncheck()">
    <input type="radio" name="radioc" onclick="radioUncheck()">
    <input type="radio" name="radiod" onclick="radioUncheck()">
    <input type="radio" name="radioe" onclick="radioUncheck()">
    <input type="radio" name="radiof" onclick="radioUncheck()">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your HTML so we can ensure you are selecting the elements correctly too

Comment: inside the body tag and inside the form i simply use an onclick for the function

Comment: <input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radiob" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radioc" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radiod" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radioe" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radiof" onclick="radioUncheck()">

Comment: Is the HTML inside of a form named `"form"`?

Comment: sadly yes, with ther id form as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` to check for equality, not `=` (which is assignment).

In addition, you are not selecting your radio button elements correctly. There is no need for array index `[1]`.

Finally, using if-else like this will mean it gets stuck at the first checked radio box when trying to rest them. Instead try to reset and all then check the one that was clicked.

For example:

```
function radioUncheck(){
    document.forms.form.radioa.checked = false;
    document.forms.form.radiob.checked = false;
    document.forms.form.radioc.checked = false;
    document.forms.form.radiod.checked = false;
    document.forms.form.radioe.checked = false;
    document.forms.form.radiof.checked = false;

    this.checked = true;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/b6fw39kw/)

Comment: <input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radiob" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radioc" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radiod" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radioe" onclick="radioUncheck()">
<input type="radio" name="radiof" onclick="radioUncheck()">

Comment: its halfway working now with = ''; and removing the array (before they were grouped) but it only goes backwards and unchecks, if i try to click back upwards the button stays stuck...

Comment: it also works with = false; but still can only go backwards without getting stuck.. is there a way to assign .reset? Maybe that would work

Comment: it does not check anything, im sorry to be a burden i appreciate you for trying to help me

Comment: @brigitte18: I provided you with a JSfiddle of it working, what is different from what you have? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: OOH THANK YOU!!!! i tryed to copy paste but adding document.forms.form.radioa.onclick = radioUncheck; within the curly bracket fixed the issue!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Can i please ask one last question, when i create local storage they dissapear when i click  but when i reload the page it shows any radio button that was clicked as checked. Can you give me a paypal so i can buy you a coffee or beer..

Comment: adding a different value for each resolved my issue?!?!?! Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Use checked = '' to remove the checked state of a radio.

Like this:

```
document.forms.form.radioa[1].checked = '';
```